# axis label restoring to original position after hiding series

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

In [my NVD3 chart here](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/vfe2B/39/embedded/result/), I have shifted the X-axis label downward so as to go with the vertically aligned dates. For that I did:

```
xTicks.select('.nv-axislabel').attr("y", 90);  // line # 81 in JS
```

Now the problem is that if I hide any of the series using the control on the top right, this X-axis label restores to its original position which is behing the dates.

How do I get it to stay at the new position, unaltered?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/vfe2B/39)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhat of a dirty solution, but may be good enough:

After changing the `y` attribute of the label, remove the class which is used by d3 internally to pick the label and reset its attributes:

```
xTicks.select('.nv-axislabel')
    .attr("y", 90)
    .classed({'nv-axislabel':false});
```

Then, as it would appear d3 just creates a new label in the unwanted position, you can add this to the CSS file:

```
.nv-x .nv-axislabel {
    display:none;
}
```

I added it as a rule because doing it programatically (using `.style()`) takes too long and you can see it flicker.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vfe2B/47/)

Answer (score 2):

If you update your NVD3 library, to version [1.1.11b](http://nvd3.org/assets/js/nv.d3.js)

You can use the in-built feature of rotating the labels. Try this :

```
chart.xAxis
 .tickPadding(-5).rotateLabels(-90);
```

Change the `x` attribute of `.tick major > text` to `10` to move the position a bit lower.

Then you will **NOT** need the following code :

```
// translate and rotate x-axis ticks
var xTicks = d3.select('.nv-x.nv-axis > g').selectAll('g');

xTicks.selectAll('g > .tick > text')
.attr('transform', function(d, i, j) {
    return 'translate (-10, 40) rotate(-90 0,0)'
});

// move x-axis label down
xTicks.select('.nv-axislabel').attr("y", 90)
```

Hope it helps